# How get the total sum of NSNumber's from a NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber, nsinteger

I have a large `NSArray` containing `NSNumbers` like `3, 4, 20, 10, 1, 100,` etc...

How do I get the total sum of all these NSNumbers `(3 + 4 + 20 + 10 + 1 + 100 + etc...)` as one total `NSInteger`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can use this:

```
NSArray* numbers = //array of numbers
NSNumber* sum = [numbers valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. Docs here:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: This is definitely the most elegant solution. However there's a small problem. If one of the elements in the array is NSNull, it crashes.

Comment: Also it's documented to do all arithmetic with `double`s. So, five years later, with the 64-bit runtime and `NSInteger` now being the same size as a `double`, that risks loss of precision when numbers are large.

Comment: Does anyone know how to perform those `@sum.self` in Swift?

Comment: This also suffers from poor performance if the array has 1000s of numbers. Better to use fast-enumeration instead

Answer (score 20):

```
NSInteger sum = 0;
for (NSNumber *num in myArray) {
  sum += [num intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
long long sum = ((NSNumber*)[array valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.longLongValue"]).longLongValue;
```

Comment: `valueForKeyPath:` returns an object, not an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through the array

```
int count = [array count];
NSInteger sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sum += [[array objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[[numbersArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] integerValue]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int total = 0;
for (NSNumber *number in array)
{
  total += [number intValue];
}
```

may this will help you