# how to add total number for NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like

```
NSString* str = @"[\"40.00\",\"10.00\",\"60.05\"]";
```

I need the total string amount "110.05"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get the total sum of NSNumber's from a NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192503/how-get-the-total-sum-of-nsnumbers-from-a-nsarray)

Comment: @EICaptain
my code:- 

for(int i=0;i<[_orderObj.itemArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *atemp=[_orderObj.itemArray valueForKeyPath:@"price"];
        NSLog(@"title %@", atemp);
        
    }
OutPut:- 
title (
    "440.00",
    "510.00",
    "560.00"
)

How get the total sum from nsstring

Comment: @SaurabhGupta : check my answer... is that you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

**1. Make an array out of the string. Since the array is in JSON format, you can do it like this:**

```
NSString* str = @"[\"40.00\",\"10.00\",\"60.05\"]";
NSArray *stringArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

**2. Convert the strings to double and add them up**

```
double sum = 0;
for (NSString *value in stringArray) {
    sum += [value doubleValue];
}
```

**3. Convert the sum back to a NSString:**

```
NSString *sumStr =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", sum];
```

Note that approaches that convert `NSString` to `double` or `float` may cause rounding errors, to overcome this issue you must use [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
float myTotal = 0;
for(int i=0;i<[_orderObj.itemArray count];i++) {
    NSString *atemp=[_orderObj.itemArray valueForKeyPath:@"price"];
    NSLog(@"title %@", atemp);
    myTotal = myTotal + [atemp floatValue];
}
NSLog(@"final total==%f", myTotal);
```